# Download file using Wget yammer export data

Tags: wget, yammer

I create console application that export data from yammer to local using wget
third party tool
and this is the reference 
https://developer.yammer.com/docs/data-export-api

the function that execute script:

```
internal static bool ExecuteScript()
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
            Process p = new Process();
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p = Process.Start(startInfo);

            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("wget -O export.zip -t 1 --header \"Authorization: Bearer %Token%\" -ca-certificate cacert.pem https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/export?since=2016-02-09T00:00:00z");

            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"exit");

            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
            p.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Error:" + error);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;

        }

    }
```

i replace %Token% with my token 
but when run the code it cut off download and create export.zip file 0KB
it's not download complete file
it show this message in console

[Console application output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ8Zu.png)

although i take this script in batch file and run it from cmd in same path it download complete file

notes:
1- I add Wget path to Path Environment 
2- I'm using windows 10
3- I'm using VS 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i discover the issue

```
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("wget -O export.zip -t 1 --header \"Authorization: Bearer <Access Token>\" --ca-certificate=cacert.pem cacert.pem https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/export?since=2016-02-09T00:00:00z");
```